# how to stay on application in iphone when you call someone from application?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I am calling a number from my application, using following code, but it will transfer control tou application call"All Contact" as I end the call, but I want to stay on same page, as I end the call,

```
 NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel://%@", number_display.text];

NSURL *url = [ [ NSURL alloc ]
              initWithString:str];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

how can I do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Only the user can switch back to your app.  And Apple has implemented the 4/5 finger swipe for quick access.

Comment: I thought the multi-finger gestures are still developer only.

Comment: In the [SDK 4.3 release notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-4_3/_index.html), it does they are not releasing it customers.  But if the public upgrade to latest version they can enable it themselves [How to enable multitasking gestures in iOS 4.3](http://www.engadget.com/2011/03/14/how-to-enable-multitasking-gestures-in-ios-4-3/)

Comment: You know almost no one is going to install (after buying or registering) Xcode just to do this :)
It certainly couldn't be a prerequisite for @Veer's problem.